# Android: AsyncTask causing spontaneous error part way through database import

Tags: java, android, sql, import, android-asynctask

The section of code below is responsible for running an AsyncTask with ProgressDialog when it is the first running of a particular version of the database.

However, an error occurs part way through, with this LogCat output:

```
02-02 17:54:12.370: D/dalvikvm(579): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
02-02 17:54:13.210: I/dalvikvm(579): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-02 17:54:13.330: I/dalvikvm(579): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-02 17:54:13.640: D/gralloc_goldfish(579): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-02 17:57:53.650: I/System.out(579): DISPLAYING HERE
02-02 17:57:53.661: I/System.out(579): Inside ManipulateDatabase constructor, initialLaunch = false
02-02 17:57:53.661: I/System.out(579): New DBH created
02-02 17:57:53.700: I/System.out(579): TABLES DROPPED FOR DOWNGRADE
02-02 17:57:53.700: I/System.out(579): PIECE TABLE CREATED
02-02 17:57:53.711: I/System.out(579): SPECIFIC TABLE CREATED
02-02 17:57:53.711: I/System.out(579): QUOTE TABLE CREATED
02-02 17:57:53.721: I/System.out(579): ELEMENT TABLE CREATED
02-02 17:57:53.721: I/System.out(579): STATS TABLE CREATED
02-02 17:57:53.721: I/System.out(579): Initial launch has been set to: true
02-02 17:57:53.731: I/System.out(579): onPreExecute
02-02 17:57:53.831: I/System.out(579): do in background!
02-02 17:57:53.831: I/System.out(579): INITIAL LAUNCH BLOCK INITIATED
02-02 17:57:53.831: I/System.out(579): PieceInsertion: 
02-02 17:57:53.841: I/System.out(579): A View from the Bridge,1: INSERTION SHOULD HAVE JUST FINISHED
02-02 17:57:53.841: I/System.out(579): PieceInsertion: 
02-02 17:57:53.841: I/System.out(579): An Inspector Calls,1: INSERTION SHOULD HAVE JUST FINISHED
02-02 17:57:53.841: I/System.out(579): PieceInsertion: 
02-02 17:57:53.841: I/System.out(579): Of Mice and Men,0: INSERTION SHOULD HAVE JUST FINISHED
02-02 17:57:53.841: I/System.out(579): PieceInsertion: 
02-02 17:57:53.851: I/System.out(579): Of Mice and Men HAS JUST BEEN ADDED TO PIECE ARRAYLIST FETCHED FROM DB
02-02 17:57:53.860: I/System.out(579): ViewNovel
02-02 17:57:54.090: D/dalvikvm(579): GC_CONCURRENT freed 119K, 3% free 9397K/9607K, paused 7ms+7ms
02-02 17:57:54.120: W/dalvikvm(579): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
02-02 17:57:54.130: I/dalvikvm(579): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-02 17:57:54.180: I/dalvikvm(579): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-02 17:57:54.950: E/AndroidRuntime(579): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-02 17:57:54.950: E/AndroidRuntime(579): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-02 17:57:54.950: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
02-02 17:57:54.950: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
02-02 17:57:54.950: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
02-02 17:57:54.950: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
02-02 17:57:54.950: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-02 17:57:54.950: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
02-02 17:57:54.950: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-02 17:57:54.950: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-02 17:57:54.950: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-02 17:57:54.950: E/AndroidRuntime(579): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.lawson.englishlitrevision/databases/EnglishDatabase.db (conn# 0) already closed
02-02 17:57:54.950: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyDbIsOpen(SQLiteDatabase.java:2082)
02-02 17:57:54.950: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:639)
02-02 17:57:54.950: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransactionNonExclusive(SQLiteDatabase.java:576)
02-02 17:57:54.950: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.acquireAndLock(SQLiteStatement.java:247)
02-02 17:57:54.950: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:112)
02-02 17:57:54.950: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1718)
02-02 17:57:54.950: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1591)
02-02 17:57:54.950: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at com.lawson.englishlitrevision.ManipulateDatabase$ImportLitData.doInBackground(ManipulateDatabase.java:1102)
02-02 17:57:54.950: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at com.lawson.englishlitrevision.ManipulateDatabase$ImportLitData.doInBackground(ManipulateDatabase.java:1)
02-02 17:57:54.950: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
02-02 17:57:54.950: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-02 17:57:54.950: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  ... 5 more
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579): Activity com.lawson.englishlitrevision.GenList has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@412d3268 that was originally added here
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.lawson.englishlitrevision.GenList has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@412d3268 that was originally added here
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:344)
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at com.lawson.englishlitrevision.ManipulateDatabase$ImportLitData.onPreExecute(ManipulateDatabase.java:1199)
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at com.lawson.englishlitrevision.ManipulateDatabase$DatabaseHelper.onCreate(ManipulateDatabase.java:984)
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at com.lawson.englishlitrevision.ManipulateDatabase$DatabaseHelper.onDowngrade(ManipulateDatabase.java:1014)
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:168)
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at com.lawson.englishlitrevision.ManipulateDatabase.openSesame(ManipulateDatabase.java:486)
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at com.lawson.englishlitrevision.ManipulateDatabase.getPieces(ManipulateDatabase.java:512)
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at com.lawson.englishlitrevision.GenList.displayList(GenList.java:223)
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at com.lawson.englishlitrevision.GenList.onCreate(GenList.java:80)
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-02 17:57:55.750: E/WindowManager(579):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-02 17:58:00.270: I/dalvikvm(1029): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-02 17:58:00.290: I/dalvikvm(1029): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-02 17:58:00.640: D/gralloc_goldfish(1029): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-02 17:58:01.410: I/System.out(1029): DISPLAYING HERE
02-02 17:58:01.420: I/System.out(1029): Inside ManipulateDatabase constructor, initialLaunch = false
02-02 17:58:01.420: I/System.out(1029): New DBH created
02-02 17:58:01.450: I/System.out(1029): Of Mice and Men HAS JUST BEEN ADDED TO PIECE ARRAYLIST FETCHED FROM DB
02-02 17:58:01.450: I/System.out(1029): ViewNovel
02-02 17:58:03.181: I/System.out(1029): PURPOSE = ViewNovel
02-02 17:58:03.181: I/System.out(1029): Check length after thingy = ViewNovel
02-02 17:58:03.181: I/System.out(1029): List item clicked!
02-02 17:58:04.031: I/System.out(1029): CHOSEN CHARACTER
02-02 17:58:04.031: I/System.out(1029): New put in thing is: ViewNovel/Of Mice and Men/Char
02-02 17:58:04.050: I/System.out(1029): DISPLAYING HERE
02-02 17:58:04.061: I/System.out(1029): Inside ManipulateDatabase constructor, initialLaunch = false
02-02 17:58:04.061: I/System.out(1029): New DBH created
02-02 17:58:04.081: I/System.out(1029): Tried to get Char elements and put in array
02-02 17:58:04.081: I/System.out(1029): ViewNovel/Of Mice and Men/Char
02-02 17:58:04.230: D/dalvikvm(1029): GC_CONCURRENT freed 129K, 3% free 9379K/9607K, paused 5ms+3ms
```

**I would be grateful if anyone could alert me as to the source of the error.**

**EDIT**

Line 1102 is: `dataBase.insert(pieceTable, null, pv);` 
Which is responsible for inserting a new piece into the Database table 'pieceTable'.

This is the respective code:

```
/**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param contextIn
     *            Context of the MainpulateDatabase class
     * @throws IOException
     */

    public ManipulateDatabase(Activity contextIn,
            ProgressDialog progressDialogIn) throws IOException {
        System.out
                .println("Inside ManipulateDatabase constructor, initialLaunch = "
                        + initialLaunch);
        context = contextIn;
        baseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        progressDialog = progressDialogIn;

    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Database helper - Three basic methods - required database tasks
     * 
     * @author Daniel Lawson
     * @version 30/12/13
     */

    private class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private DatabaseHelper(Context theContext) {
            super(theContext, databaseName, null, databaseVersion);
            System.out.println("New DBH created");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            try {
                db.execSQL(createPieceTable);
                System.out.println("PIECE TABLE CREATED");
                db.execSQL(createSpecificTable);
                System.out.println("SPECIFIC TABLE CREATED");
                db.execSQL(createQuoteTable);
                System.out.println("QUOTE TABLE CREATED");
                db.execSQL(createElementTable);
                System.out.println("ELEMENT TABLE CREATED");
                db.execSQL(createStatsTable);
                System.out.println("STATS TABLE CREATED");
                initialLaunch = true;
                System.out.println("Initial launch has been set to: "
                        + initialLaunch);
                ImportLitData ild = new ImportLitData(progressDialog, context);
                ild.execute("none");

            } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to create table(s)");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + pieceTable);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + specificTable);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + quoteTable);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + elementTable);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + statsTable);
            System.out.println("TABLES DROPPED FOR UPGRADE");
            onCreate(db);

        }

        @Override
        public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
                int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + pieceTable);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + specificTable);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + quoteTable);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + elementTable);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + statsTable);
            System.out.println("TABLES DROPPED FOR DOWNGRADE");
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private class ImportLitData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        /**
         * ProgressDialog in which progress is shown
         */
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        /**
         * Context of class from which the TXTs will need to be imported -
         * Context of the AsyncTask
         */
        private Activity context;

        /**
         * Boolean to store whether import of data from text file was successful
         * or not
         */

        private Boolean success;

        /**
         * Constructor method
         * 
         * @param dialogIn
         *            Progress Dialog which will be updated
         * @param contextIn
         *            context of Class
         */
        public ImportLitData(ProgressDialog dialogIn, Activity contextIn) {
            // progressDialog = dialogIn;
            context = contextIn;
            setUpDialog();
        }

        /**
         * Sets up the download progress dialog
         */
        private void setUpDialog() {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Importing initial data");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            // progressDialog.show();
        }

        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            System.out.println("do in background!");
            BufferedReader pieceScan;
            BufferedReader specificScan;
            BufferedReader elementScan;
            BufferedReader quoteScan;
            try {
                pieceScan = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        getPieceTextFile(context), "UTF-8"));
                specificScan = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        getSpecificTextFile(context), "UTF-8"));
                elementScan = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        getElementTextFile(context), "UTF-8"));
                quoteScan = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        getQuoteTextFile(context), "UTF-8"));

                openSesame();
                String line;
                String pieceName;
                String isDrama;
                String point;
                String element;
                String quote;
                String isCharacter;
                int commaPoint;
                int commaPoint2;

                System.out.println("INITIAL LAUNCH BLOCK INITIATED");
                while ((line = pieceScan.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("PieceInsertion: ");
                    commaPoint = line.indexOf(",");
                    pieceName = line.substring(0, commaPoint);
                    isDrama = line.substring(commaPoint + 1, commaPoint + 2);
                    ContentValues pv = new ContentValues();
                    pv.put(pieceField, pieceName);
                    pv.put(typeField, (Integer.parseInt(isDrama)));
                    dataBase.insert(pieceTable, null, pv);
                    System.out.println(line
                            + ": INSERTION SHOULD HAVE JUST FINISHED");
                }

                while ((line = specificScan.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("SpecificInsertion: ");
                    commaPoint = line.indexOf(",");
                    point = line.substring(0, commaPoint);
                    commaPoint2 = (line.substring(commaPoint + 1,
                            line.length() - 1).indexOf(",")) + point.length();
                    // pieceName = line.substring(commaPoint + 1,
                    // commaPoint2 +
                    // 1);
                    element = line.substring(commaPoint2 + 2, line.length());

                    ContentValues sv = new ContentValues();
                    sv.put(pointField, point);
                    // sv.put(pieceField, pieceName);
                    sv.put(elementField, element);
                    dataBase.insert(specificTable, null, sv);
                    System.out.println(line
                            + ": INSERTION SHOULD HAVE JUST FINISHED");
                }

                while ((line = elementScan.readLine()) != null) {
                    commaPoint = line.indexOf(",");
                    element = line.substring(0, commaPoint);
                    commaPoint2 = (line.substring(commaPoint + 1,
                            line.length() - 1).indexOf(",")) + element.length();

                    pieceName = line.substring(commaPoint + 1, commaPoint2 + 1);
                    isCharacter = line.substring(commaPoint2 + 2,
                            commaPoint2 + 3);

                    ContentValues ev = new ContentValues();
                    ev.put(elementField, element);
                    ev.put(pieceField, pieceName);
                    ev.put(elTypeField, (Integer.parseInt(isCharacter)));
                    dataBase.insert(elementTable, null, ev);
                    System.out.println(line
                            + ": INSERTION SHOULD HAVE JUST FINISHED");

                }

                while ((line = quoteScan.readLine()) != null) {
                    commaPoint = line.indexOf("^");
                    quote = line.substring(0, commaPoint);
                    System.out.println("Quote = " + quote);
                    point = line.substring(commaPoint + 1, line.length());
                    System.out.println("Point = " + point);

                    ContentValues qv = new ContentValues();
                    qv.put(quoteField, quote);
                    qv.put(pointField, point);
                    dataBase.insert(quoteTable, null, qv);
                    System.out.println(line
                            + ": INSERTION SHOULD HAVE JUST FINISHED");
                }

                success = true;

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                System.out.println("Unsupported Encoding Exception!");
                e.printStackTrace();
                success = false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("IO Exception!");
                e.printStackTrace();
                success = false;
            }

            return success;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            System.out.println("onPostExecute");
            progressDialog.cancel();

            String toastMessage = (result) ? "Imported" : "Import Failed";
            Toast resultOut = Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            resultOut.show();

        }

        /**
         * Method called before doInBackground is executed
         * 
         * @override
         */
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            System.out.println("onPreExecute");
            /* Dialog shown */
            progressDialog.show();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: can u please specify what exactly is line 1102 of manipulateDatabase.java? might help in the diagnosis

Comment: Certainly, line 1102 is:

dataBase.insert(pieceTable, null, pv);

Which is responsible for inserting a new piece into the Database table 'pieceTable'.

Comment: I've also added this to the initial post.